# Issue modifying Jupyter Home Directory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

At one point I set my Jupyter home directory to `~/Dropbox`  Unfortunately, because of the way Dropbox changed their folder name that location is now a symbolic link on my machine that points to a hidden directory.  This causes the following error in Jupyter

`Refusing to serve hidden directory '/Users/alex/Dropbox', via 404 Error`

That's fine ... I'd like to now change my Jupyter home directory, but the issue I'm having is that I can't figure out where it's currently set.

I've checked my `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` but that seems to be unmodified from the default.

The output of `$jupyter --paths` is :

```
config:
    /Users/alex/.jupyter
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /Users/alex/Library/Jupyter
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /Users/alex/Library/Jupyter/runtime
```

Interestingly, the following directories don't exist.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/etc/jupyter
/usr/local/etc/jupyter
/etc/jupyter
```

Setting `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = '/Users/alex/'` in `/Users/alex/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` seems to have no effect.

```
$jupyter notebook
[I 18:26:34.756 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 4 kernels found
[I 18:26:35.257 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:26:35.258 NotebookApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:26:35.259 NotebookApp] The port 8890 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:26:35.260 NotebookApp] The port 8891 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:26:36.299 NotebookApp] [nb_anacondacloud] enabled
[I 18:26:36.304 NotebookApp] [nb_conda] enabled
[I 18:26:36.382 NotebookApp] ✓ nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
[W 18:26:36.382 NotebookApp] ✗ nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module named 'nbbrowserpdf'
[I 18:26:36.388 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/alex
[I 18:26:36.388 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 18:26:36.388 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 18:26:36.388 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8892/?token=289948463daed06187325be63202f620b812dddc14f2918a
[I 18:26:36.388 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 18:26:36.389 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8892/?token=289948463daed06187325be63202f620b812dddc14f2918a
[I 18:26:36.717 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[I 18:26:37.252 NotebookApp] Refusing to serve hidden directory '/Users/alex/Dropbox', via 404 Error
[W 18:26:37.252 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1526088397023 (::1): directory does not exist: 'Dropbox'
[W 18:26:37.252 NotebookApp] directory does not exist: 'Dropbox'
[W 18:26:37.253 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1526088397023 (::1) 15.70ms referer=http://localhost:8892/tree
```

Where could the Jupyter home directory be set from?

Answer (score 3):

It is the intended behavior of `jupyter notebook` to [throw a 404 when starting it from a hidden folder](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2382).

Generally, `jupyter notebook` will start in the folder where you invoke the `jupyter notebook` command. So `cd` into the directory where you want it to run from, and issue `jupyter notebook` there.

If that doesn't work, you can try forcing the directory with a command line argument like `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=NEWDIR`.

Otherwise, there is a global config and a local (per user) one you refer above. If the local is the default, then you probably changed the global config earlier. If you change your local config in `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` to the new value that should override the global config.

To clean up the global config, look for it in `/etc/jupyter` or `/usr/local/etc/jupyter/` on Unix or `%PROGRAMDATA%\jupyter\` in Windows.

You can list the current config paths used with the command `jupyter --paths`. More info in the [manual](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html#id1).

Comment: Thanks for you comments .. I've added more detail based on your suggestions but still no luck.

Comment: What's your OS? Also, have you tried to change directory where you want to run jupyter from and just issue the `jupyter notebook` command from there?

Comment: macOS 10.13.4 (17E202) ... using anaconda `conda -V
conda 4.5.2`.  Regardless where I try to run `jupyter notebook` from it defaults to `~/Dropbox`

Comment: Have you tried `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=NEWDIR`?

Comment: Now we are getting somwhere ... `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=NEWDIR` works but that's clearly a pain to do every time.

Comment: Happy to hear. :) trying to think of something... if it knows it should go to `~/Dropbox` then that has to be stored somewhere... Can you do a grep on your etc folder?

Comment: By the way the output you posted has this line: `[I 18:26:36.388 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/alex` so that means it's serving the right folder. `~/Dropbox` is just a subfolder there it's trying to list. Did it completely fail to load the whole page in your browser or just the dropbox folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170888/discussion-between-agf1997-and-peter-szoldan).